# Pawn Movement in Chess Game - Java

Tags: java, android, logic, chess

There is an issue with the movement in the chess app I am creating. Here is the method that checks if a move is valid:

```
public boolean isMove(int row, int col, Pawn[][] board){
    Pawn p = board[row][col];  
    int direction = 1; 
    if (this.color=='w') { 
        direction = -1;
    }
    if (p == null && this.col == col && ((this.row + direction) == row) || (this.row + 2 * direction) == row && ! this.hasMoved) { //can move
        return true;
    }
    else if (p != null && p.color != this.color && row == (this.row + direction) && (col == (this.col - 1) || col == (this.col + 1))) { // can capture
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here are some outputs that I am getting:

[image]

This move should not be valid, but yet it allows to move to that square. I am thinking there is an issue with the method I posted above.

Comment: have you debugged it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `&&` and `||` are conflicting in priorities/order.

Maybe:

```
if (p == null && this.col == col && (this.row + direction) == row || this.row + 2 * direction == row && ! this.hasMoved)
```

Should be:

```
if (p == null && this.col == col && ((this.row + direction) == row || this.row + 2 * direction == row) && ! this.hasMoved)
```

I don't have a game so I cannot try it but...

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure `this.hasMoved` is only tied to the +2 direction test only. Otherwise everything but the inital move will be invalid. This should work for your first if statement:

```
if (p == null && (this.col == col && (((this.row + direction) == row) ||((this.row + (2 * direction)) == row && !this.hasMoved))))
```

You will need to correct the piece capture statement on your own. Make sure you use proper bracketing between conditionals.